# Error when running OTEL collector with Jaeger in Docker containers

Tags: docker-compose, jaeger, open-telemetry-collector

I'm trying to run jaeger and an OTEL collector as docker containers.
Unfortunately I run into the following error message:

otel-collector  | Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:
error decoding 'exporters': unknown type: "jaeger" for id: "jaeger" (valid values: [logging otlp otlphttp file kafka prometheus debug opencensus prometheusremotewrite zipkin])

My docker compose file looks as follows:
`

```
version: '3'
services:
  otel-collector:
    container_name: otel-collector
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./Configuration/collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "4317:4317"

  jaeger:
    container_name: jaeger
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14250"
```

The config file for the collector looks as follows:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
processors:
  batch:
exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, jaeger]
```

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jaeger is not a valid exporter for the latest otelm collector. Currently the following exports are allowed:

- debug
- logging
- otlp
- azuredataexplorer
- googlecloud
- influxdb
- prometheusremotewrite
- datadog
- instana
- mezmo
- sapm
- signalfx
- otlphttp
- azuremonitor
- cassandra
- dataset
- opencensus
- awscloudwatchlogs
- googlemanagedprometheus
- logicmonitor
- loki
- tencentcloud_logservice
- file
- alibabacloud_logservice
- awsemf
- awskinesis
- awsxray
- carbon
- clickhouse
- dynatrace
- loadbalancing
- sumologic
- f5cloud
- kafka
- prometheus
- sentry
- skywalking
- zipkin
- awss3
- elasticsearch
- logzio
- pulsar
- splunk_hec
- coralogix
- googlecloudpubsub
- tan
- zuobservability

To fix, Change to otlp:

```yaml
otlp:
    endpoint: jaeger:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
```

Example in otelm demo chart: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/blob/0def0da3d8beb5e95840e62c614fd616694c287e/charts/opentelemetry-demo/values.yaml#L627